# Rails 4 - Showing Order Parameters in Thank You page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ecommerce app in rails 4. When an order is placed, I redirect to a thank you page. I want to show order details in the thank you page.

What do I put into the thankyou method below to get order details in the thank you view? Or do I need to change the route? Note that my thankyou route is a standalone route.

```
#routes
resources :listings do
  resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update, :show]
end

get 'thankyou' => "orders#thankyou"

#order controller
def thankyou
end

#thankyou.html
Thank you for your order - <br>
<%= @order.id %><br>
<%= @order.listing.name %><br>
<%= @order.price_sold %><br>
```

Comment: From the code that you have provided, when redirected to the 'thankyou' action, there is no @order object. You need to pass the object to the Thankyou action or find it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the thank you route include the order ID:

```
# routes.rb
resources :listings do
  resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update, :show] do
    member do 
      get :thankyou
    end
  end
end

# order controller
def thankyou
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can redirect to the new thankyou route with `thankyou_listing_order_path(order)`